# Deserialize object one by one from file .Net

Tags: c#, json, .net, memory, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a list of heavy objects from a json file. I do not want to deserialize it the classic way, like directly to a list, because it will expose me to an OutOfMemory exception. So I'm looking for a way to handle object one by one to store them one by one in the database and be memory safe.

I already handle the serialization and it's working well, but I'm facing some difficulties for deserialization.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

```
 // Serialization 
    using (var FileStream = new FileStream(DirPath + "/TPV.Json", FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(FileStream))
        {
            using (var jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                jw.WriteStartArray();
                using (var _Database = new InspectionBatimentsDataContext(TheBrain.DBClient.ConnectionString))
                {
                    foreach (var TPVId in TPVIds)
                    {

                        var pic = (from p in _Database.TPV
                                   where Operators.ConditionalCompareObjectEqual(p.Release, TPVId.Release, false) & Operators.ConditionalCompareObjectEqual(p.InterventionId, TPVId.InterventionId, false)
                                   select p).FirstOrDefault;
                        var ser = new JsonSerializer();
                        ser.Serialize(jw, pic);
                        jw.Flush();

                    }
                }
                jw.WriteEndArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code is in VB not c#...

Comment: I know, but tagging c# will give more visibility

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly found a way to do it by using custom separator beetween each object during serialization. Then for deserialization, I simply read the json file as string until I find my custom separator and I deserialise readed string, all in a loop. It's not the perfect answer because I'm breaking json format in my files, but it's not a constraint in my case.